# OpenVPN with no internet access

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I am using OpenVPN and am able to connect, but with no internet access anymore.

Here is my ip table:

```
sshadmin@mdpi1:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         my.live.ip.adr  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
my.live.ip.adr  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U         0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

Here is the server configuration:

```
### General config
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
client-to-client

### Certificates
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem

### User permissions
user nobody
group nogroup

### VPN network subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

### Varia
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun

### Logging
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn

### Push network config (default gateway and DNS server)
push "redirect-gateway local def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"

### User authentication settings
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name

### Management interface
management localhost 7505
```

Any idea why there is a problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the OpenVPN server and client configuration?

Comment: A little more information on the server and client configuration would be nice but I guess you don't have a NAT configured on the server side for the VPN network. You have to NAT the traffic going to 0.0.0.0 from 10.8.0.0. Or you have add "route-nopull" in the client config (to use your local internet connection). You will have to update your routes to the server though, see OpenVPN documentation on setting routes on the client side.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, I updated my question with the server config file.

Comment: @Broco, thank you for your comment. I updated my question with the server config file. Do you know how to create this nat? In the IP table? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to route all traffic via the OpenVPN tunnel, or just access some site via OpenVPN? If it is the former, then you need to implement NAT. You can find several guides for NAT in Google. If the latter, then you need to remove the two `push` options.

Comment: My goal is to access some sites over OpenVPN, so use the server's IP address. I tried to remove the push but then the OpenVPN is using my local internet because I am on the internet with my local public IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by editing the Push network config and bypass the dhcp:

```
### Push network config (default gateway and DNS server)
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.2"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.0.2"
```